# SSL Cert Showing as Untrusted in FireFox 4.0.1

Tags: ssl-certificate

I pushed out a new EV SSL cert for our site, it is working in all browsers we have tested but not consistently in FireFox 4.0.1, Some users report the problem for that version of FireFox but some don't I haven't been able to track it down and see what the problem could be.

Any help is welcome the url is https://www.empathic.com

Comment: Works ok for me.  Your using a comodo cert though and I would not be surprised if some firefox extension out there were to generate a warning purely based on it being a comodo cert!

Comment: Thanks I will keep digging and check with those users and have them turn off all plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its a bit late, but it could be this issue:

http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html

The recommended resolution in the link is:

> To fix this error, you will need to install one or more
>   intermediate/chain certificates onto the web server. If you have any
>   questions about how to do this, contact your certificate authority or
>   follow their SSL certificate installation instructions.

I've been getting a similar issue with a Comodo certificate recently.

Comment: It was related to the certificate chain, I recently switched over to using aws elb, and I was able to get everything working now.